# TcPDF: Different Page Sizes

Tags: php, symfony, tcpdf

I'm trying to generate a single PDF file from multiple PNG images.

I've 3 images and I'd like that the size of each page was the same that the size of each image.

The problem is that when I use the `AddPage` method it keeps the same dimensions from the first page.

This is my code where each of the elements of `file_names` array is a PNG file path:

```php
$pdf = $this->container->get("white_october.tcpdf")->create(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setMargins(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
for ($i=5; $i<8; $i++){
  $size = getimagesize($file_names[$i]);
  $width = $pdf->pixelsToUnits($size[0]);
  $height = $pdf->pixelsToUnits($size[1]);
  $resolution= array($width, $height);
  $pdf->AddPage('L', $resolution);
  $pdf->lastPage();
  $pdf->setMargins(0, 0, 0);
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
  $pdf->Image ($file_names[$i], 0, 0);

}
$pdf->Output($file_names[8].".pdf", 'F');
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
```

OR

```
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5');
```

OR

```
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A6');
```

AND so on